# Can I tell when a waitable timer will fire by its handle?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timer

Say, if I created a waitable timer using [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and then set it using SetWaitableTimer. Can I find out when that timer will fire only by the HANDLE returned by the first API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

But there is nothing preventing you from creating a wrapper object that will publish a similar API, record the target time (by adding the due time to the current time when `SetWaitableTimer` is called), and provide the outstanding time to you as a difference between the current time when the query method is called, and the target time.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's what I'm doing now, but I observed that if the system time changes (say, due to daily time adjustments, or more mundanely, manually by an admin user) the timer fires at a different time than when I set it, obviously because the system time was adjusted, and my "wrapped" datetime variable does not reflect such change. That is why I thought to get the time from the timer handle directly.

Comment: @ahmd0 - If you implementing a rule, like, "if less than 1 minute to firing, then wait, otherwise just cancel the timer", you can do that by creating two timers, one of them firing 1 minute before the main one.  That will behave correctly with system time changes.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice solution. Complex one though :( I was just looking for an easy fix...